# Problem with mysql DELETE from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I was using this query:
DELETE T1, T2
FROM table1 T1, table2 T2

It seems to work inconsistency in mysql.

If both tables contain rows, then all row in each are deleted, as I expected.
But if one table is already empty, then the other table will be ignored and not have any rows deleted.

Is this correct behaviour or is it a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct behavior.

Test this to observe that the cross product join against a table with no rows returns an empty result:

```
mysql> select * from table1, table2;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to ensure to include rows from table1, use an outer join:

```
mysql> select * from table1 left join table2 on true;
+----+------+
| id | id   |
+----+------+
|  1 | NULL |
|  2 | NULL |
|  3 | NULL |
+----+------+
```

I'm using SELECT just to demonstrate that a non-empty result is returned. You can use the same kind of join with DELETE, and see it does delete the rows.

```
mysql> delete table1, table2 from table1 left join table2 on true;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table1;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

You may ask what if table1 has no rows, and you want to delete from table2. Or you don't know if either table has no rows. Then you would need a FULL OUTER JOIN, but MySQL doesn't support that type of join.

Why not just run two DELETE's serially? If you're deleting all the rows, there is no benefit to doing it in one joined DELETE statement.

```
DELETE FROM table1;
DELETE FROM table2;
```

If you need these to be committed together, then start a transaction and commit it after both deletions are completed.